# Is there a way to ping your mobile on activity?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Is there a way to ping your mobile if there is activity on your question or answer?

I think it would require a SE app. But bottom line is everything is more and more mobile/tablet/phablet. I normally try to hang around once I have posted something. But it could become moot to keep refreshing the page to see if I got any replies to a question.

Is it possible to get this feature?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/
I'm sure there's something that will do what you want.

Comment: maybe http://stackapps.com/q/2370 is of interest, I don't know whether it shows notifications though

Answer (score 5):

Under the *Settings* tab on your profile, under 'Email settings', there's an option to get emailed when you have a new notification. Using this and an email app on your phone with push notifications enabled, you can kind of get the functionality you want.

[image: Email notification settings]

It's not instant, but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in a few questions' activity, the easiest way is probably checking its RSS feed - just look at the bottom of the right-hand column, above the footer:

[image: where's the RSS button?]